# MySQL multiple sort and ignores?

Tags: mysql, sorting

Made a test sqlfiddle if anyone wants to attempt this...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/904e18/2/0

In my database I have this:

```
Group: A
Name: A-1, Points: 7pts
Name: A-2, Points: 6pts
Name: A-3, Points: 6pts
Name: A-4, Points: 5pts

Group: B
Name: B-1, Points: 1pts
Name: B-2, Points: 5pts
Name: B-3, Points: 4pts
Name: B-4, Points: 6pts

Group: C
Name: C-1, Points: 6pts
Name: C-2, Points: 8pts
Name: C-3, Points: 9pts
Name: C-4, Points: 2pts
```

I need to sort it first by the **overall leader** with the most points. (C-3)

Then I need to sort it by the **second** overall leader, but **not** in the group of the **overall leader**. (A-1)

Next, I need to sort it by the **third** overall leader, but **not in the the group** of the overall leader or second leader (B-4)

Then sort the rest by points.

So it should like this:

C-3
A-1
B-4
^^The leaders of each group, sorted by highest to lowest
-----
Then the remaining ones by points highest to lowest, no group specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the top-3 teams in the way you want with the following query:

```
select * from teams
where points = (select max(points) from teams as t where t.`group` = teams.`group`)
order by points desc
```

You can also get the rest of the teams in the way you want with the following query :

```
select *  from teams
where name not in 
  (select name from teams
  where points = (select max(points) from teams as t where t.`group` = teams.`group`))
order by points desc
```

The problem is that if you union those 2 queries, then you will lose any ordering they contain. So, in order to combine those 2 results, you will have to add a ***sortKey*** in the 2 results and use it in the ordering of the final result, in order to retain the ordering. The query is the following :

```
(select *, 1 as SortKey from teams
where points = (select max(points) from teams as t where t.`group` = teams.`group`))

UNION ALL

(select *, 2 as SortKey from teams
where name not in 
  (select name from teams
  where points = (select max(points) from teams as t where t.`group` = teams.`group`)))

order by SortKey, points desc
```

You can also see it in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/904e18/76)

Comment: Wow! Awesome. Do you think it would be possible to sort the rest of them by points after?

Comment: Wow, I really didn't know MySQL was capable of such impressive queries.... I really appreciate it, got lots to learn! THANK YOU

Comment: You 're welcome. You can also upvote/accept my response, if it successfully solved your problem.